# Xlib XDefineCursor flickering

Tags: c++11, cairo, xlib, mouse-cursor

In Xlib I'm using the XDefineCursor function to change the mouse pointer to a variety of cursors that I'm generating from the XCreatePixmapCursor function.  I'm finding that the cursor does indeed change as expected, but when it does so a strange flashing/flickering occurs between cursor changes, where the cursor quickly and erratically jitters in place before reappearing in the proper position.  It happens really fast but it's pretty noticeable.  Is it possible to have a smooth transition between cursor changes?  Or am I doing something incorrectly?  Thanks!

**Update:**

I think that the hotspots used during the Pixmap cursor definitions are related to this issue.  Each cursor I'm using has its own unique hotspot associated to itself depending on the way the cursor looks.  I found that when I simply set all the hotspot values to (0, 0) that the flickering goes away.  Unfortunately, this means I have incorrect hotspots for the cursors.  Ex:

```
// before, causes flicker
cursor1_pointer = XCreatePixmapCursor(dpy, cursor1_source, cursor1_source,
  &foreground_color, &background_color, 16, 15);

// after, no flicker
cursor1_pointer = XCreatePixmapCursor(dpy, cursor1_source, cursor1_source,
  &foreground_color, &background_color, 0, 0);
```

I'm guessing that Xlib is attempting to reposition the cursor based on its new hotspot during the change.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be doing so in a visually graceful way.  Any ideas?

**Update:**

I figured out a semi-clunky trick to prevent this flickering.  Basically, I edited the cursor image files to all have a sufficiently large and shared canvas size, and then repositioned each cursor image within this space such that all cursors used in the program could share a common hotspot pixel coordinate (16, 16).  That way when Xlib updates the cursor, it doesn't have to reposition the cursor according to the new images hotspot, allowing for a semi-smooth visual transition.

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.